# I downloaded Tor and can't for the life of me OPEN it

Tags: mac

I downloaded Tor and can't for the life of me OPEN it. I am on a Mac os Sierra 10.12.6
I have spent about 45 minutes with two people and it's just a dead, flat file - more like an image of a file than something that will open. Other files will open, so it's not my mouse or something. I also tried downloading from a different browser. Still nothing. I tried copying it into the applications folder and it's there, but still just flat and won't open. [image]

Comment: Are you able to mount other .dmg files? Do you ger an error message if you try to mount it using the command line? http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/17/mount-a-dmg-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: To be super extra clear, you are clicking on the DMG file and nothing happens, right? Just to be sure you or someone else with the same problem isnt overlooking something, here is a video showing how to install on os x: https://youtu.be/b6ZWC-wQjL0

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your Mac to 10.13.2 (17C88) by opening the App Store and clicking the updates tab, and install any updates you see.
2. After your Mac is updated, right click on `TorBrowser-7.0.11-osx64_en-US.dmg` and click `Open`.
3. a popup should show up. Drag TorBrowser onto the `/Applications` folder.
   click on launchpad and TorBrowser should show on one of the pages.
4. If you can not find it, open Finder and Click on `Applications` and it should be in that list.